# Compare three columns of two files

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files that have some similar and some unique columns. I'd like to compare the first 3 columns that are similar and print if they match, along with each of their unique columns.

File1:

```
A cat pizza 34 24 56 
A dog tomato 304 959 030
B bird grape 4.4 939 33
C snake broccoli 89 28 273
```

File2:

```
A cat pizza 55 85 328
B dog tomato 404 56 32
C snake sandwich 384 34 75
```

Which should make

File3:

```
A cat pizza 34 24 56 55 85 328
```

I've been trying

```
awk  'NR==FNR       {c[$1$2$3]++;next}
      c[$1$2$3] > 0 {print $0}'
```

but I'm not getting any matches.

Comment: Actually I do get matches. If I create `file1` and `file2` as above, and run your unchanged command with the two files as parameters, I do get `A B C G H I`. However, what output do you want to generate when there is more than one match, e.g. more than one line starts with `A B C`?

Comment: I'd recommend you use `c[$1,$2,$3]` (with commas) -- that puts a separator between the strings so you won't get false positives, such as `A A AA` in file 1 and `AA A A` in file 2

Comment: Are your files single line? If no, you should post a realistic sample. Do the files have equal line numbers?

Comment: Your description is a bit unclear: So you want all columns but no double entries? Are columns really always the same or is it just about the headers? Please add better example files.

Comment: There are so many ways to interpret this.... what if A B C doesn't appear in file2? What if it appears multiple times in either or both files? When you say `I'd like to compare the first 3 columns that are similar` do you mean you **always** want to compare **only** the first 3 columns or you literally want to compare the first 3 columns that are similar out of N that might be similar, and, by similar do you actually mean identical or something else, and does order matter such that A B C in file1 matches A C B in file2, etc.? Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback: I've changed my question to clarify!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like

```c
function join(start, end, sep,       str, i) {
    if (!sep) sep = OFS
    str = $start
    for (i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) str = str sep $i
    return str
}
 
          { key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 }
NR == FNR { f1[key] = join(4, NF); next }
key in f1 { print key, f1[key], join(4, NF) }
```

Run with

```bsh
awk -f script.awk file1 file2
```

Comment: Note that, given "along with each of their unique columns", this does not ensure the subsequent columns are _unique_. It takes the common 3 columns, and all the rest of them appended, even if they are not strictly unique. I assumed this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it's not necessary that the columns are unique.